# Custom Bootstrap Tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there some sort of class that helps me draw vertical lines between columns?

Like, if I have 10 columns, is it possible to make a 2px line between column 1 and column 2 and 4px line between column 9 and column 10?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="your_table_parent_div">
    <div class="coloumns">
        <div class="coloum1 fleft"></div>
        <div class="coloum2 fleft"></div>
        <div class="coloum3 fleft"></div>

        ...
        <div class="coloum9 fleft"></div>
        <div class="coloum10 fleft"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="your_table_data_div">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
.your_table_data_div{
     position:relative;
}
.your_table_parent_div{
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
}
.cloumns{
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;

}
.column1,.column2{
border-right:2px;
}
.column9,.column10{
border-right:4px;
}
```

Comment: You have typed "column" in at least three different ways in this complete mess.

Comment: Also, are we sure citizen_of_noobville is not referring to the actual table/tr/td elements instead of divs?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap gives you lot of features but the one you demanded is not listed so you should try n-th child property to get the column border using border-right or left:2px; as per requirement or as Yogesh answered specify them manually that would be better